# Deactivate protrusion for active character `«

Tags: microtype, catcodes

Is ist possible to deactivate `microtype`’s protrusion for certain characters only? I’m trying to make `«#1»` a shortcut for `\fbox{#1}` but it won’t work unless I deactivate protrusion completly.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\usepackage[
%   protrusion = false,
]{microtype}

\catcode`« = \active
\def«#1»{
   \fbox{#1}
}

\begin{document}
   Test «Test» \fbox{Test}
\end{document}
```

I won’t need the guillemets character in the output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just get an annoying warning, but the active character works.

In order to remove the warning, delay the activation.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\usepackage[
%   protrusion = false,
]{microtype}

\protected\def\activeguill#1»{%
   \fbox{#1}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`« \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\activeguill
  \catcode`«=\active
}

\begin{document}

Test «Test» \fbox{Test}

Test \fbox{Test} \fbox{Test}

\end{document}
```

The output would be the same with your code, though (provided spurious spaces are removed).

[image]

Comment: With the code in my post I get an _error_ not a _warning_ (arg has extra `}`) … and the spaces are there because I normally use expl3 syntax, and forgot to add `%` here …

Comment: @Tobi I have delete my post. There is the superlative egreg. :-). +1   also for egreg.